# python modifying dictionary values to another dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
a = {'aaa_key': ['aaa/aaa.csv', 'aaa/aaa.csv', 'aaa.csv'], 'bbb_key': ['bbb/bbb.csv', 'bbb/bbb.csv', 'bbb.csv']}
```

and I want to split `/` signs in inner lists values. 
I use this code and `print` gives me right values like

```
aaa_key [['aaa', 'aaa.csv'], ['aaa', 'aaa.csv'], ['aaa.csv']]
```

and

```
bbb_key [['bbb', 'bbb.csv'], ['bbb', 'bbb.csv'], ['bbb.csv']]
```

but when i try to print aa dictionary, it's lists happen to be empty `{'aaa_key': [], 'bbb_key': []}`. What am i doing wrong?
[code sample](https://repl.it/BEDF)

```
b = []
aa = dict()
for i in a:
    for ii in a[i]:
        b.append(str(ii).split('/'))
    print str(i) + ' ' + str(b)
    aa[i] = b
    del b[:]

print aa
```

Comment: The dictionary is filled with references to *exactly the same list*, which you carefully empty at the end of each loop iteration. Try `aa[i] = b[:]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `b` to a dictionary value actually both the values and the `b` refer to one object and when you delete it with `del b[:]` actually you delete both.So you need to remove that part.

But as a more pythonic way you can simply use a [*dictionary comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to create your expected dictionary :

```
>>> {key:[i.split('/') for i in value] for key,value in a.items()}
{'aaa_key': [['aaa', 'aaa.csv'], ['aaa', 'aaa.csv'], ['aaa.csv']], 'bbb_key': [['bbb', 'bbb.csv'], ['bbb', 'bbb.csv'], ['bbb.csv']]}
```

Note that you can also reassign to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are purging the content of the list `b` it also purges the content of the dictionary values that was assigned from the same variable. Both the variable `b` and the dictionary value refers to the same list

Instead of purging the content, just associate the variable `b` to the reference of a new list, every time you loop in a new key.

**Implementation**

```
def foo(a):
    aa = dict()
    for i in a:
        b = []
        for ii in a[i]:
        b.append(str(ii).split('/'))
        aa[i] = b

    return aa
```

**Sample Run**

```
>>> foo(a)
{'aaa_key': [['aaa', 'aaa.csv'], ['aaa', 'aaa.csv'], ['aaa.csv']], 'bbb_key': [['bbb', 'bbb.csv'], ['bbb', 'bbb.csv'], ['bbb.csv']]}
```